# How to save a "zoom" image in google street view

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem to save "google street image view" when I zoom in or zoom out the pictue.

For example I have picture link something like this:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?sensor=false&zoom=1.6600000000000001&heading=0&size=640x640&location=47.371693,8.535608000000025

is same with:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?sensor=false&zoom=2.3200000000000003&heading=0&size=640x640&location=47.371693,8.535608000000025

But in this link zoom property makes no sense. Some other property maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Zoom* property doesn't exist. You can zoom on an image by using *fov* property.

For example:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?sensor=false&heading=0&size=640x640&location=47.371693,8.535608000000025&fov=20

From [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/):

> fov (default is 90) determines the horizontal field of view of the image. The field of view is expressed in degrees, with a maximum allowed value of 120. When dealing with a fixed-size viewport, as with a Street View image of a set size, field of view in essence represents zoom, with smaller numbers indicating a higher level of zoom.

Comment: Thanks it works.
For dinamic zoom i catch the zoom_changed event and calculate fov value something like this: (found here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/uqKfg0ZBhWc)

zoom=0 ----> fov=120
zoom=1 ----> fov=90
zoom=2 ----> fov=53.5
zoom=3 ----> fov=28.3
zoom=4 ----> fov=14.3
zoom=5 ----> fov=10

So:
var values=[120, 90, 53.5, 28.3, 14.3, 10]; var zoom=panorama.getPov().zoom;
var fov=values[Math.round(zoom)];

Answer (score 0):

There is no `zoom` parameter at streetview image app.

You can use `fov` parameter instead of it.

zoom is between `0 - 5`  // 5 is the closest point

fov is between `0 - 120`  // 0 is the closest point

the easiest way to find fov from zoom:

```
var $fov = 120 - ((120 / 5) * zoom);
```